# iOS 10 Widget backgroundColor changed darktextColor?

Tags: widget, ios10, today-extension

iOS10 The default background is white,

I want to change to a transparent black color.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Set the **Today extension** `UIViewController` `view's` color from `storyboard` itself.

[image]